# Laravel raw query that counts results per month and aggregates

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following query

```
$this->builder = (DB::table('sales')
        ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(sale_date, "%M") as sale_date'), DB::raw('count(*) as sales'))
        ->where('sale_date', '>', $lookback->toDateTimeString())
        ->orderBy('sale_date', 'asc')
        ->groupBy('sale_date'));
```

Despite specifying the month `%M` to group the results, it's just counting each date and giving the label as the month, so something like this:

```
sale_date , sales
 August   ,  1
 August   ,  3
 August   ,  2
```

Instead of what I expect:

```
sale_date , sales
 August   ,  6
```

What am I doing wrong here, I do have the option of just summing those within the javascript once I get the results from the API, however I don't think it should be necessary right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try group by `DATE_FORMAT(sale_date, "%M")`, You have assigned alias named as `sale_date` which is also name of your column so try to use different name for your alias or put the complete expression in group by

```
$this->builder = (DB::table('sales')
        ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(sale_date, "%M") as sale_month'), DB::raw('count(*) as sales'))
        ->where('sale_date', '>', $lookback->toDateTimeString())
        ->orderBy('sale_date', 'asc')
        ->groupBy('sale_month'));
```

Not sure if `DB::raw()` works in `groupBy()`

```
->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(sale_date, "%M")'))
```

Comment: yep the groupBy with `DB::raw` works - thanks the only thing I didn't try :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution  would be like :

```
  $this->builder = (DB::table('sales')
    ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(sale_date, "%M") as sale_month'),
     DB::raw('sum(count) as sales'))
    ->where('sale_date', '>', $lookback->toDateTimeString())
    ->orderBy('sale_date', 'asc')
    ->groupBy('sale_month'));
```